# cywin bash script command not found when called from batch

Tags: bash, cygwin

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Testing"
cd "/cygdrive/x/Internal Communications/Riccardo/"
filename=htdocs-`date +%A`.tar.gz
tar cvzf $filename "/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Zend/Apache2/htdocs"
```

The above script is working when it is called inside cygwin console, but when I try to call it from a batch file I get "command not found" for date and tar command. I think that bash.exe does not have the PATH set up.

I need to run that script from that batch file because I want to add the script to the task scheduler.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put your cygwin bin directory (likely `C:\cygwin\bin`) on your PATH environment variable.

This would also give you the benefit of being able to use commands like `tar`, `ls`, `rm`, etc. from a regular console windows and not just a Cygwin console.

Comment: Hi, I've added the path (i'm sure this is the correct path) but ls,grep,etc commands are still not found. any idea?

Answer (score 17):

As has already been said, you need to add the Cygwin binaries to your path. To do so, right click on "My Computer", click "Properties", then "Advanced", then "Environment Variables".

Create a new environment variable with name "CYGWIN_HOME" and value "C:\cygwin" (or wherever you installed cygwin. The default location is "C:\cygwin\" so this should probably work for you).

Then edit the environment variable named "PATH", and tack on the following to the end:

;%CYGWIN_HOME%\bin;%CYGWIN_HOME%\sbin;%CYGWIN_HOME%\usr\bin;%CYGWIN_HOME%\usr\sbin;%CYGWIN_HOME%\usr\local\bin;%CYGWIN_HOME%\usr\local\sbin

Close your command prompt, then reopen it. The cygwin binaries should now be available. You can double-check this by typing "which bash". It should report the location of your bash executable.

Answer (score 12):

FWIW, Cygwin has [cron](http://www.newmedialogic.com/node/33).

Are you calling your script like this?

```
bash --login -i ./myscript.sh
```

Comment: Of the people who have posted answers so far, seth is the only person who recognizes that putting C:\cygwin\bin on the path doesn't allow Windows to magically understand bash scripts.  You need to send your script to bash.exe.

Comment: The batch is: C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe "C:\backup.sh"
I think I have not installed cron in cygwin. Do I need to install it only or do I have to do some more config to use cron? Thanks mate!

Comment: @rtacconi - it's more than just installing.  The link I have in my answer goes through the steps of installing/configuring cron

Answer (score 2):

If this script is invoked from a Windows command shell, the first line will result in an error since `#!/bin/bash` is not a recognized Windows command and `#` is not a valid comment delimiter in a batch file.

So, the bottom line is that this script runs as a regular batch file rather than from within Cygwin's bash.  As noted by `matt b`, you likely do not have the Cygwin executable path in your PATH environment variable.  Without this, the batch file cannot find the Cygwin utilities (`tar` and `date`).

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem.

Editing the environment variable works great. But if you are have no admin rights you can´t do that. 
In this case you can execute your commands by using the absolute path like:

```
/usr/bin/tar cvzf $filename
/usr/bin/cat $filename
```

If you do so your bash script works even if you call it from a batch file.